# Finding image and inverse function in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be open subset which is surrounded by lines:

$y=x;~ y=2x;~ x+y=1;~ x+y=3$

and $m:= \frac{y}{x},~ s:=x+y$ for $(x,y) \in V$, so it follows that $y= \frac{ms}{m+1}, ~ x= \frac{s}{m+1}$.

Why does follow that $\Psi: V \rightarrow \mathbb R^2, \Psi(x,y):=(\frac{y}{x}, x+y)$ is injective?

And what is/ how to compute the image $U:=\Psi(V)$ and the inverse function $\Phi:=\Psi^{-1}:U \rightarrow V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Psi$ is injective if $\Psi(u) = \Psi(v)$ implies $u = v$.

With $u = (x, y)$ and $v = (x', y')$ we have
$$
\Psi(u) = (y/x, x+y) = \Psi(v) = (y'/x', x' + y')
$$
From $V \cap \{ (0, y) | y \in \mathbb{R} \} = \emptyset$ and
$$
(y/x  = y' / x' ) \wedge \, (x + y = x' + y')
$$
we infer
$ x - x' = y' - y$ and 
$y x' = y' x$ which gives 
$$
y (x' - x) = y x' - y x = y' x - y x = (y' - y) x
$$
and requires $x' - x = y' - y = 0$ for $x \ne y$. Thus $x = x'$ and $y = y'$ follows.

For the image: the boundary of $V$ is described by four lines and their intersection points, look at how $\Psi$ maps them to the boundary of $U$.

[image: U]
[image: V]

Inverse map: $\Psi(x,y) = (m, n) \Rightarrow \Psi^{-1}(m,n) = (x, y)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

1. Calculate the Jacobian of $\Psi$, which is the same as the Jacobian of the change of variables. Is it everywhere of the same sign? If so, then the function is one to one
2. In $m, s$ coordinates what are the bounds of the region $V$? As $\Psi(x,y) = (m(x,y), s(x,y))$, that gives you the bounds on the region $U = \Psi(V)$
3. It looks like you've calculated the inverse function already! I.e., given the functions $m(x,y)$ and $s(x,y)$, what is $x = f_1(m, s)$, $y = f_2(m,s)$